# Fast way to search the properties of objects in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I have an `NSArray` of custom objects that all have a @property `name` of type `NSString`. How can I quickly enumerate through the array and create a new array that contains only the objects that have a specific word in their `name` property?

For instance:

```
CustomObject *firstObject = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
firstObject.name = @"dog";

CustomObject *secondObject = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
secondObject.name = @"cat";

CustomObject *thirdObject = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
thirdObject.name = @"dogs are fun";

NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:firstObject,
                                                             secondObject,
                                                             thirdObject, 
                                                             nil];

// I want to create a new array that contains all objects that have the word 
// "dog" in their name property.
```

I know I could use a for loop like so:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (CustomObject *obj in testArray)
{
    if ([obj.name rangeOfString:@"dog"].location == NSNotFound) {
        //string wasn't found
    }

    else {
        [newArray addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

But is there a more efficient way? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *searchString = @"dog";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains %@", searchString];
NSArray *filteredArray = [testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: I don't know what would the syntax exactly be, but shouldn't the predicate check for SELF.name instead of SELF itself?

Comment: @DrummerB This will not work because the testArray contains objects, not strings. I want to search for the word in the object's property and not the object itself.

Comment: Ah, didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, the single quotes need to be removed from around `%@` to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at `NSPredicates` ! They are highly efficient when you are searching / filtering through array results. This is the  [documentation!](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

Comment: Perhaps an example for my specific situation?