# iOS loop through NSMutableArray of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a efficient way too loop through an `NSMutableArray` containing custom objects?

This is how to init and add objects to my `NSMutableArray`:

```
self.messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
[self.messages addObject:[[JSMessage alloc] initWithText:message sender:name date:myDate livePreview:@"1"]];
```

What i want to do specifically is to loop through the `NSMutableArray` and look for where the "livePreview"  key is 1 and then update the message on that object.

How could this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast way to search the properties of objects in an NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12099867)

Comment: A `for` loop is as "efficient" as anything.  You can use blocks if you want multi-threading, et al, but that's not as efficient, nor is using KVC/predicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (JSMessage * message in self.messages) {
   if ([message.livePreview isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
      message.message = @"updated message";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at NSArray's block based [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) to inspect the elements

`- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block`